# Python Google Drive API discovery.build fails with exit code -1073740777 (0xC0000417)

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am building a python application which uploads images to google drive. However after working for some some time my google drive upload suddenly stopped working. Whenever I try to initialize the service, the program exits with code -1073740777 (0xC0000417).

I have already tried to create a new client_secret.json file with the developer console (also with a completely different Google account) and deleting the drive-python-quickstart.json credential file.

My friends do not have this problem with the same code and as I said, this has worked for me for some time, too, but suddenly stopped working.

I am running Windows 10 Pro x64 with Python 3.5 32 Bit.

The problem occurrs when running this example program (taken from [the Google quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/python)):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'drive-python-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Drive API.

    Creates a Google Drive API service object and outputs the names and IDs
    for up to 10 files.
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

    results = service.files().list(maxResults=10).execute()
    items = results.get('items', [])
    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['title'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have fixed the problem myself eventually.

After a little bit of debugging, I found out the following:

The oauth2client can use two different methods for opening a file. It first tries to import the class _Win32Opener and when the import fails it uses the _FcntlOpener. The import of _Win32Opener does not fail but the opening and locking of a file using the _Win32Opener fails so the program crashes. To force oauth2client to use the _FcntlOpener, just remove/rename the file `_win32_opener.py` in your pyhton packages.

Relevant files:

```
[PythonDir]/Lib/site-packages/oauth2client/contrib/locked_file.py
[PythonDir]/Lib/site-packages/oauth2client/contrib/_win32_opener.py
```

**tl;dr**

Just remove/rename the file

```
[PythonDir]/Lib/site-packages/oauth2client/contrib/_win32_opener.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem while working with Google Youtube API, also had the same os (Win 10 Pro x64) and used the same version oh python (3.5).

I have no idea how but adding this line in the main function helped

```
sys.modules['win32file'] = None
```